# Eclipse PHP PHPUnit - Eclipse use the wrong php.ini file

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit

I try to use PHPUnit and each time when I load the tests the php.ini file loaded is this one :

> C:\Users\Jerome\AppData\Local\Temp\zend_debug\session6671704870793012233.tmp\php.ini

instead of :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\apache\php.ini

I don't get it because in Run -> Run debug configurations ...

in alternate PHP "PHP X debug" is selected which is configured right as the screenshot shows it :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior of PDT. PDT with Xdebug creates two copies of the specified PHP ini file into your temporary directory when launching a script. The first one is the same as the specified PHP ini file. The second one is what is really used for the launch.

In the second one, the include_path field is always removed. Additionally some fields are added into the bottom of the file as follows:

```
--- /path/to/specified/php.ini
+++ /path/to/temp/zend_debug/session2594175249121649690.tmp/php.ini
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@@ -785,7 +786,6 @@
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
-include_path = "..."
 ;
 ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
 ;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
@@ -1852,3 +1852,6 @@
 ; Local Variables:
 ; tab-width: 4
 ; End:
+
+date.timezone= "Asia/Tokyo"
+memory_limit = "256M"
```

### How to solve the include_path for launching?

Basically, the PHP Include Path property is used to solve dependencies for a project. Especially, PHPUnit is solved by a user library which is defined in the workspace preferences. See the following images.

[image: Configuring PHP Libraries]

[image: Using PHP Libraries in PHP Include Path]

Comment: Thanks iteman yes that is my specific problem is that i need to set the include path with the PHPUnit libraries so, any idea how to do that? Or to use the first one?

Comment: Use User Libraries to do that. The first one is just a temporary file and no chance to modify by hand. See the answer and http://blog.chrisrogers.me.uk/eclipse-phpunit-xdebug-makegood-and-ubuntu-php-unit-testing/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to solve this, but my preferences were already configured this way :/
I'm really lost on this one ^^ I will look at the link thanks again !