# Eclipse PDT + xdebug: memory_limit "hardcoded" to 256Mb

Tags: php, eclipse, memory, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

Using Ecplise PDT & xdebug for debugging PHP scripts, it seems a duplicate of the configured php.ini file is automatically created, adding a couple of lines at the end of the copy.
This has been exposed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473545/eclipse-php-phpunit-eclipse-use-the-wrong-php-ini-file/30729429#30729429)

This is a real problem in my case because a "hardcoded config" includes a memory_limit set to 256Mb while some of my scripts expect to have up to 1G, as I have configured in all the php.ini environments I'm working on.

A "fix" would of course be to add a ini_set() call to all scripts involved but I don't consider this as an acceptable solution to cope with a surprising behaviour of PDT!

I have searched for xdebug options and played with Eclipse startup settings such as -XX:MaxPermSize, without success.

I cannot debug some of the scripts that require lot of memory except by temporarly adding the ini_set() call.

If anybody can help modify the 256M option or even better get rid of this extra line of config added to the session ini file, that would be of a great help.

Comment: I registered PDT bug for you: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470047

Comment: Thank you @zulus, hope this will be taken into account!

Answer (score 0):

This was a [pdt bug](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470047) and has been fixed. Test build available in [nightly repo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Nightlies), will be released together with Eclipse 4.5.1 (PDT 3.6)